# Ubuntu saying "Volume group ubuntu-vg not present" before prompting for password

Tags: boot, lvm, luks

Ubuntu 16.04 isn't prompting for my luks password. I pressed ctrl+alt+F1, and the output says "Volume group ubuntu-vg not present."

Of course not! I haven't been asked for my password! ubuntu-vg doesn't appear until sda5 is decrypted!

How do I get luks to ask for a password?

Comment: Will someone please answer this? I have encountered this problem many times and have always had to spend hours of fruitless googling before coming to an obscure solution and then forgetting the result by the next time the problem manifests.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling to successfully pass an encryption password prompt on Ubuntu 20.04. Escaping the graphical prompt by ESC key, there was a message:

```
Volume group ubuntu-vg not present.
No key available with this passphrase.
```

I made several attempts to activate LUKS partition from USB flash. There was no change after boot.

Finally, I figured out that the keyboard scheme was changed (from US to CZ) and I was really entering the wrong password. You can test it in grub after boot.